# Problema al sincronizar base de datos en MYSQL Workbench (error 1064)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Buenas tengo el siguiente código con las siguientes tablas:

https://arandurapeedu-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/5540379_mec_edu_py/EX72yKt9GNxBvTQWF2YZQTYBz7zlAE2pDwezScLcSx3W8w?e=3LASRF

Al compilar el código me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COMMENT = 'Tabla que indica el producto...' at line 7
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Producto` (
          `idProducto` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Campo que indica el código del producto.',
          `descrip_prod` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Campo donde se indica la descripción de un producto.',
          `prec_com_prod` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Campo que indica el precio de compra del producto',
          `cant_prod` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Campo donde se indica la cantidad del producto que se adquiere.',
          PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`),
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
        COMMENT = 'Tabla que indica el producto con sus atributos'

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Tengo mi versión de MYSQL Workbench actualizada a la última versión (27/09/21), y no sé cuál podría ser la solución a este problema..

Comment: Entre la lineas que comienzan con `PRIMARY KEY` y `ENGINE` te falta algo.

Comment: Prueba con `PRIMARY KEY (\`idProducto\`))`

Comment: Me vuelve a marcar un error, ahora en la línea 6..

Answer (score 0):

Según el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html), la sintaxis de `CREATE TABLE` es esta:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

El problema en tu caso es que **no estás cerrando con paréntesis el bloque de `create_definition`**, que es donde declaras las columnas, índices, llaves, restricciones, etc. Dicho bloque terminaría aquí: `PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`),` y **estás dejando una coma en vez de cerrar con paréntesis**.

Así debería funcionar:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Producto` 
    (
      `idProducto` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Campo que indica el código del producto.',
      `descrip_prod` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Campo donde se indica la descripción de un producto.',
      `prec_com_prod` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Campo que indica el precio de compra del producto',
      `cant_prod` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Campo donde se indica la cantidad del producto que se adquiere.',
       PRIMARY KEY (`idProducto`)
    )
       ENGINE = InnoDB
       DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
       COMMENT = 'Tabla que indica el producto con sus atributos'
```